# Pass initial state in dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use the method `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` with my own initial_state. The state of the cell which is given to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` is a tupel. I don't understand the documentation:

> If cell.state_size is a tuple, this should be a tuple of tensors having shapes [batch_size, s] for s in cell.state_size.

How can I pass my shape (batchSize, hiddenSize) so that the elements of hiddenSize are initial state for the hidden and the cell state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an LSTM state tupel with the init method `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(c, h)` and pass that tupel to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` to initialize the state.